# StructureMap, ObjectFactory and the IContainer

Tags: c#, structuremap, objectfactory

I'm working with StructureMap for my IoC needs.

To make things pleasantly testable, I'm passing `IContainer` instances around wherever possible, usually as constructor parameters. As a convenience, I'd like to be able to fall back to using `ObjectFactory` for a parameterless constructor.

The simplest way (I thought) to do this would be to simply get the `IContainer` the `ObjectFactory` class wraps and pass that to the other constructor. Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere this instance is publicly exposed.

The question is:

Is there a way to get the `IContainer` within `ObjectFactory` so I can handle it as simply as a user-supplied instance?

Alternatively, is there a way to duplicate the configuration of the `ObjectFactory` into a new `Container` instance?

**Example:**

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Container = ... // The ObjectFactory container instance.
    }

    public MyClass(IContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public IContainer Container { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: If my answer missed the mark. Can you give a usage example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ObjectFactory exposes a Container property which gives you the IContainer you are looking for.

Anytime you need an IContainer (which should not be often) you can always take a dependency on it in your class ctor.

```
public class INeedAContainer
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public INeedAContainer(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

I do not think there is a way to clone an IContainer. There is a container.GetNestedContainer() method which allows you to keep your transients the same for the lifetime of the nested container. Nested containers are often used within a "using" statement and are very handy for controlling the state of things like database transaction boundaries.

Comment: I'm not sure if that provides me an answer. I've updated my question to clarify the scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I pawed over `ObjectFactory` and didn't find any `Container` property. After your answer said there should be one, I updated to the latest version and violla! Thanks.